# Janus WebRTC video streaming not working on 4G connection

Tags: video, vpn, android, ios, webrtc

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the issue we have. We have a client who's company works with video intercom which sends video streaming to the mobile phone it calls. For that purpose they have configured a server with Janus as WebRTC with STUN/TURN server configured. The video intercom uses Android as OS, and they have developed an Android and iOS webrtc for their client's smartphones.

When an user calls through the video intercom the connection between the video intercom and the smartphone (Android or iOS) client app is established.
The video streaming works well BUT only with WiFi and if they use 4G connection they must use a VPN.

The problem they have is that the video intercom does not send video streaming if they connect the device to 4G WITHOUT a VPN, but it works when they use a VPN. It also works well with WiFi (with or without VPN).

What could be the problem?

Thanks again in advance for the help and sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you find the cause, yet ?

Comment: Hi @GeneVincent, see my answer below. I hope it helps you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue I solved the problem updating the libwebrtc library to the latest one (available in that moment (2019)):

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.23171'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.0'
implementation'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.0'
```

Updating those three dependencies to those versions worked like a charm